# Kineticjs Groups of shapes can be dragged out of stage and mousedown outside stage, loses the shapes

Tags: html, kineticjs

Kineticjs Groups of shapes can be dragged out of stage and mousedown outside the stage loses the shapes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes...

By default shapes can be dragged out of the group and even dragged off stage.

You can limit the shapes drag to a specified area using dragBoundFunc.

Here's a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/bP92U/

```
var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
  x: 20,
  y: 20,
  width:50,
  height:30,
  fill: 'blue',
  draggable: true,
  dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
    var w=this.getWidth();
    var h=this.getHeight();
    if(pos.x<0){pos.x=0;}
    if(pos.x+w>sw){pos.x=sw-w;}
    if(pos.y<0){pos.y=0;}
    if(pos.y+h>sh){pos.y=sh-h;}
    return {
      x: pos.x,
      y: pos.y
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I am afraid to say that adding dragBoundfunc didn't fix my problem.

Comment: dragBoundFunc is the way to go...give it another try! Here's another reference: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-shapes-horizontally-or-vertically-tutorial/